# Groupby two clolumns, max from another two columns and other values according to max values in grouped columns

Tags: python, group-by

source data:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| qwe | asd | TRUE | 2 | 123 | 999 |
| qwe | asd | TRUE | 4 | 456 | 888 |
| qwe | asd | FALSE | 4 | 789 | 777 |
| qwe | asd | TRUE | 3 | 101 | 666 |

groupby columns A and B, get max value from C and D (D column always contain two similar values for C True and C False), keep values from E and F columns according to C and D max

desired output:

| A | B | C | D | E | F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| qwe | asd | TRUE | 4 | 456 | 888 |

I tried

```
columns = ['A','B']
df2.groupby(columns,as_index=False, dropna=False)[['C','D']].max()
```

result:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| qwe | asd | TRUE | 4 |

but no idea how to get E and F values

Answer (score 1):

I think you want True in priority compared to False, then the highest D.

You can use:

```
df.sort_values(by=['C', 'D']).groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).last()
```

Output:

```
     A    B     C  D    E    F
0  qwe  asd  True  4  456  888
```